# Auto Capitalize on submit AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I Auto Capitalize all the value of my dynamic text box. I want on submit for security purposes. I used strtooper in PHP but it has an array problem. And I used auto capitalization using CSS but if the value is already submitted to database it is not working, it's still the same as the value I inputted. Anyone can help me.

main form:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
  $(document).ready(function() { 
$('#submitme').on('submit', function(e) {
    var mytxt1 = [];
    var mytxt2 = [];

    $(".car_brand").each(function () {
        mytxt1.push($(this).val());
    });             
    $(".car_model").each(function () {
        mytxt2.push($(this).val());
    });     

      e.preventDefault();
       var perfTimes = $(this).serialize();
        $.post("maintenance_function.php", {results: perfTimes, txt1: mytxt1,  txt2: mytxt2 }, function (data) {

        if (data.errors) {
            var alertErrors = "The following errors were found: ";
                $.each(data.errors, function(index, error){
                alertErrors += "\n" + "\n" + error.message;//Add each error in a new line 
            });
    alert(alertErrors);
    } 
else {
    alert(data.message);
    window.location.href = data.redirect;
}
}, "json");
            });
        });


  <script>
  var nitem =0; 
  var ntotal = 0;



        $('.btn').click(function() { 
            nitem++; 
                $('#wrapper').append('<div id="div' + nitem + '" class="inputwrap">' +
                    'Car Manufacturer:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="car_brand" id="' + nitem + '" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                    'Car Model:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" class="car_model" id="' + nitem + '" required>' +

                    '<br><br></div>');  
                }); 

        $('.btn2').click(function() {           
            ntotal = $('#total').val(); 
                $("#div" + nitem).each(function(){              

                    }); 

                    $("#div" + nitem ).remove();
                        nitem--; 
                    $('#total').val(ntotal); }); 
       </script>
```

Function form:

```
        <?php
        include('connect.php');
        $mydata = $_POST["results"];
        //echo $mydata;
        parse_str($mydata);
        $inputs = [];
        parse_str($mydata, $inputs);
        extract($inputs);
        $errors = [];
        if(!isset($_POST["txt1"])){
        $errors[] = array(
        'error_code' => 1,
                    'message' => 'Please add a text box.'
            );


        }

        if(empty($errors)) {

for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST["txt1"])-1;$i++)
{
    //if (trim($_POST["txt1"][$i]) != "" && trim($_POST["txt2"][$i])  != "" &&            trim($_POST["txt3"][$i]) != ""){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_maintenance VALUES ('', '".            $_POST["txt1"][$i] ."','". $_POST["txt2"][$i] ."')");
    //}
}
$response = array(
'message' => 'Successfully Added',
'redirect' => "car_maintenance.php"//add here
        );
        echo json_encode($response);

        }
         else {
        $response = array(
            'errors' => $errors
        );

        echo json_encode($response);
}



        ?>
```

Comment: `mytxt1.push(this.value.toUpperCase());` ???

Comment: `var perfTimes = $(this).serialize().toUpperCase();`

Comment: you could force it with CSS `text-transform: uppercase`

Comment: Actually, if im right, that doesnt work (at least not crossbrowser). It will look uppercase, but on submit, the original upper/lower-case is send

Comment: @Martijn you are right!

Comment: @Martijn Not working sir.

Comment: @A.Wolff you code is working. Sir can I ask what code should I insert? I want the first letter is going uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

use this on the string you want to capitalize in the php file:

```
$newstring = ucwords(strtolower($string1));
```

this will create “title case,” where the first
letter of each word is in uppercase and the rest of the letters are in lowercase, hopw this is what you meant.

if you want all letters capital, use this:

```
$newstring = strtoupper($string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **css**

`input {text-transform:uppercase;}`

In **javascript**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').value = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value.toUpperCase()
```